# c++ linked backtrace path

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an algorithm - very performance sensitive that goes through a graph and make some decisions. As part of it I have to create a backtrace for the solution I find to be the best. At every step there are multiple choices and they are evaluated again and again until at the end there is only one. At every new step current backtraces could be made a subsolution for zero or more new possible solutions.

The complexity of the algorithm does not allow tricks so what I have so far is smart pointers for the nodes where the backtraces are dynamically hooked.

```
struct Node;
typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<Node> NodeSPtr;

struct Node
{
    Node(NodePool& pool)
        : mCount(0)
    {
    }

    ~Node()
    {
    }

    size_t ref_count()
    {
        return mCount;
    }

    NodeSPtr mPreviousNode;

    size_t mCount;

    // ... some data
};
```

The problem with this is that it generates big number of small items and this slows down the algo.

The question is what other options you could suggest where both performance and memory are sensitive matters.

Comment: That sounds like the NodePool does not perform well

Comment: currently the node pool is just a stl vector that push_backs the released items and reuses them instead of new them - this improved the performance between 4/5 times. Still not good enough though.

Comment: with deque is many times slower. maintaining the linked infrastructure is expensive